# Jquery wrap group of specific elements in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<label>Name <input type="text" name="text_2"/></label>
<label>Phone <input type="text" name="text_3"/></label>
<label>Age <input type="text" name="text_4"/></label>
<label>Address <input type="text" name="text_5"/></label>
```

I want to convert above html into format given below. I tried with jQuery `.wrap()` but no success. Any help or pointers will be quite helpful.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name:<i class="mandate">*</i></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-lg">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Phone:<i class="mandate">*</i></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-lg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Age:<i class="mandate">*</i></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-lg">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Address:<i class="mandate">*</i></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-lg">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: At least show what you have tried...

Comment: Is the first Code Area a typo or your real Code? If it is you should take a look at how to close HTML-Tags ;)

Comment: Are you expecting the answer to autocorrect the typos and close the tags in html as well..?

Comment: @KingofPopup's: There. You now have an answer that auto-corrects the typos! ;)

Comment: Sorry for typo, updated question.

Comment: @pramodtech every two consecutive `.form-group` will be wrapped to a `.row`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label').each(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        $this.wrap( "<div class='row'><div class='form-group'></div></div>");
        var $child=$this.find('input[type="text"]');
        $child.remove();
        $this.parent().append($child);
        $this.append('<i class="mandate">*</i>');

    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E5366/14/)

Comment: I want two `form-groups` are wrapped in `rows`, not every one of them

Comment: I modified your code bit and found the solution. Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E5366/15/

Answer (score 0):

you input tag is not closed:

```
<label>Name <input type="text" name="text_2"/></label>
<label>Phone <input type="text" name="text_3"/></label>
<label>Age <input type="text" name="text_4"/></label>
<label>Address <input type="text" name="text_5"/></label>
```

afterwards please try (with the assumption of no other label exist on page):

```
$("label").wrap("<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"form-group\"></div></div>");
```

Comment: Every *two* `form-group`s are wrapped in `row`s, not every *one* of them.

Comment: this doesn't give required output.